Compatibility Issues with Library Versions for RAG Project Integration with Rasa
I want to create a RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) project and integrate it with Rasa. However, Rasa requires older versions of some libraries, such as Pydantic (version 1.10.10). Meanwhile, libraries like LangChain, LangChain Core, and various embeddings libraries use the latest versions of Pydantic.
To address this, I’ve decided to create my RAG project using an older version of LangChain. However, I'm facing difficulties determining which versions of other libraries are compatible with my chosen older version of LangChain.
Is there a way to check which versions of various libraries I need to install to ensure compatibility with my older Langchain version?
